# Hadoop replication factor precedence

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have this only in my namenode:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>
```

In my data nodes, I have this:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```

Now my question is, will the replication factor be 3 or 1?

At the moment, the output of `hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:///user/hadoop-user/data/0/0/0` shows 1 replication factor:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup      68313 2015-11-06 19:32 hdfs:///user/hadoop-user/data/0/0/0/00099954tnemhcatta.bin
```

Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default replication factor is `3`, it is standard in most of the distributed system. if the replication factor was set to 3 (default value in HDFS) there would be one original block and two replicas. Most of time when we working on single node cluster(single machine) that time we put it `1`. because if  we will take 3 then there will be no benefit as all the copy are on single machine. so simple understanding. in multi node cluster replication factor should be 3 used in failure and in single machine replication factor should be 1.

Comment: No, HDFS distributes replicas into distinct machines. You can check the number of replicas by using commands in https://ofirm.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/exploring-hdfs-block-placement-policy/

Answer (score 0):

Open the hdfs-site.xml file. This file is usually found in the conf/ folder of the Hadoop installation directory. Change or add the following property to hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.replication<name> 
<value>3<value> 
<description>Block Replication<description> 
<property>
```

You can also change the replication factor on a per-file basis using the Hadoop FS shell.

[jpanda@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 /my/file

Alternatively, you can change the replication factor of all the files under a directory.

[jpanda@localhost ~]$ hadoop fs –setrep –w 3 -R /my/dir